# play wave file for all browser and mobile web browser javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, wave

How to play wave file for all browser and mobile browser by javascript or other ways?

I need to play alert.wave or mp3 file but `<audio>` and `<embed>` not working on mobile web browser.

What should I do?

Do you there a way to cross browser and play this wave file

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'?  Are there errors?  Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

first make sure you're referencing the files properly.

Also check which codecs each browser uses for audio. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats

After that you should be able to play them.